# Any way to account for ascender/descender in Sketch?

Tags: text, sketch-app

When working with text, sometimes I want to align based on the top or bottom pixel of the text. However, Sketch includes the ascender and descender for spacing operations, checking distance from other layers, etc. Is there a way to just use what is actually rendered?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Sketch, but here's a guess if it's like other vector image editors. Draw a rectangle around the text, set the fill and stroke to none, then group that rectangle with the text. At least that way the text will still be editable.

If this works, give me a wink!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is select the text box, right-click and choose `Convert to Outlines`

This converts the text into a combined vectorised shape and hence all type-related accommodations are negates any then negated. The only caveat is that you cannot edit the text once converted.